# Highcharts setData maximum call stack exceed

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highcharts, and I want to click a point and have a model popup and be able to change a dropdown and change the color and symbol of the point. I can change one point, but then when I click on the next point. I get Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. Any help would be great!

```
var update;
// point click event function
function showModal(p) {  
    update = p;
    var d = moment(p.point.x).format('M/D/YYYY H:mm');
    $('#point-date').html(d);
    $('#point-value').html(p.point.y);
    $('#point-flag').val(p.point.flag);
    $('#pointModal').modal('show');
}

// Clicking save on modal
function saveFlag() {

    var newData = update.point.series.data;
    var dataPoint = newData.filter(function (r) {
        return r.SiteID == update.point.SiteID && r.Date_Time == update.point.Date_Time
    });
    if (dataPoint != null && dataPoint.length > 0) {
        var size = 2;
        if (data.length < 50)
            size = 4;

        var value = $('#point-flag').val();
        dataPoint[0].marker.radius = size;
        dataPoint[0].marker.symbol = getSymbol(value);
        dataPoint[0].colorIndex = getColorIndex(value);
        dataPoint[0].flag = value;

        for (var index in timeseries.series) {
            if (timeseries.series[index].name == update.point.series.name) {
                timeseries.series[index].setData(newData);
            }
        }
    }
    $('#pointModal').modal('hide');
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide an online demo of your example? You can start here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h9p4fkng/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dr8fg9u1/11/
This works(breaks) just like mine. I can change one value, then I can't click on the second point. I get the JS error in the console.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dr8fg9u1/12/ added colors

Comment: Hi, I modified the code slightly. Is this what you are looking for?: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6ky7v2ur/ The updating of point in Highcharts, should be done by `point.update()` method. API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that in this example `timeseries.series` refers to [this API](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart.html#series) and is an array. To loop over an array, I don't want to use `for...in`, but `for...of`, which returns each element:

```js
        for (var series of timeseries.series) {
            if (series.name == update.point.series.name) {
                series.setData(newData);
            }
        }
```

See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to update a point, and this is working for me.

```
var newData = update.point.series.data;
for (var index in timeseries.series) {
    if (timeseries.series[index].name == update.point.series.name) {
        for (var pointIndex in timeseries.series[index].data) {
            if (timeseries.series[index].data[pointIndex].SiteID == update.point.SiteID
                && timeseries.series[index].data[pointIndex].Date_Time == update.point.Date_Time) {
                    var value = $('#point-flag').val();
                    timeseries.series[index].data[pointIndex].update({
                        marker: { radius: 4, symbol: getSymbol(value) },
                        colorIndex: getColorIndex(value)
                    });
            }
        }
    }
}
```